# Modify line of code in c to NOT contain unsigned variable or casting. (?)

Tags: c, unsigned, unsigned-integer, ansi-c

How could I modify the line bellow in ANSI C without using the *unsigned* mark?

```
unsigned int x, y, z; // unsigned variables should not be used
/*... some operations where x, y and z gets values between 0x0 and 0xFFFFFFFF ... */
x = (unsigned int)-(int)(y * z); // line to modify
```

Comment: I don't understand.  The very line on which you declare three variables of type `unsigned int` is marked with a comment "unsigned variables should not be used".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can directly apply negation to an unsigned value. The result will be reduced modulo 2^N, which is what your existing code does anyway.

```
x = -(y * z);
```